# Equivalent Javascript substr_count?

Tags: javascript, string, phpjs

I am trying to find an equivalent function for Javascript.  What I am trying to do is look for the current URL and if it has the following first part of the URL then do something.

In PHP I have this

```
if (substr_count($current_url, $root . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/shop/shop-gallery') {
 doSomething();
}
```

So as long as it matches that URL and all sub URLs like /shop/shop-gallery/product1..etc, the statement will be true.

Now how can I execute the same exact statement in javascript?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You you actually what to count the substrings or just see if it's there? If it's the first, then use Frosty Z's answer, if it's the latter you shouldn't be using `substr_count` in PHP in the first place, but `strpos` instead (it's probably faster).

The JS version of the latter is the String method `indexOf`:

```
if (stringToSearch.indexOf(current_url) > -1)  {
   doSomething();
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Err... Maybe `strpos` instead of `substr` ? Anyway, I think that your answer is more appropriate since Rick wants to check if the URL "begins with" something.

Comment: I am trying to say return true if it matches /site/shop-gallery or /site/shop-gallery/anything after this.

Comment: @Frosty Oops, thinking one thing, writing another. Thanks.

Comment: @Rick: Yes, that is why `strpos` is more appropriate that `substr_count`, because you don't actually want to **count**. (`substr` was a typo)

Comment: thank you for the answer thus far but I wrote if(current_url.indexOf("shop-gallery") { doSomething(); } this always true...

Comment: ok i revised it to if(current_url.indexOf("shop-gallery") != -1) { doSomething(); } that seemed to work...

Answer (score 26):

Substr_count in JavaScript can also be implemented as follows:

```
var substr_count = hay_stack_string.split('search_substring').length - 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check http://locutus.io/php/substr_count/ for the equivalent.